# Using scipy's kmeans2 function in python

Tags: python, scipy, k-means

I found [this](http://hackmap.blogspot.in/2007/09/k-means-clustering-in-scipy.html) example for using kmeans2 algorithm in python. I can't get the following part

```
# make some z vlues
z = numpy.sin(xy[:,1]-0.2*xy[:,1])

# whiten them
z = whiten(z)

# let scipy do its magic (k==3 groups)
res, idx = kmeans2(numpy.array(zip(xy[:,0],xy[:,1],z)),3)
```

The points are `zip(xy[:,0],xy[:,1])`, so what is the third value `z` doing here?

Also what is whitening?

Any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First:

```
# make some z vlues
z = numpy.sin(xy[:,1]-0.2*xy[:,1])
```

The weirdest thing about this is that it's equivalent to:

```
z = numpy.sin(0.8*xy[:, 1])
```

So I don't know why it's written that way. maybe there's a typo?

Next,

```
# whiten them
z = whiten(z)
```

*whitening* is simply normalizing the variance of the population.  See here for a demo:

```
>>> z = np.sin(.8*xy[:, 1])      # the original z
>>> zw = vq.whiten(z)            # save it under a different name
>>> zn = z / z.std()             # make another 'normalized' array
>>> map(np.std, [z, zw, zn])     # standard deviations of the three arrays
[0.42645, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> np.allclose(zw, zn)          # whitened is the same as normalized
True
```

It's not obvious to me *why* it is whitened.  Anyway, moving along:

```
# let scipy do its magic (k==3 groups)
res, idx = kmeans2(numpy.array(zip(xy[:,0],xy[:,1],z)),3)
```

Let's break that into two parts:

```
data = np.array(zip(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], z))
```

which is a weird (and slow) way of writing

```
data = np.column_stack([xy, z])
```

In any case, you started with two arrays and merge them into one:

```
>>> xy.shape
(30, 2)
>>> z.shape
(30,)
>>> data.shape
(30, 3)
```

Then it's `data` that is passed to the kmeans algorithm:

```
res, idx = vq.kmeans2(data, 3)
```

So now you can see that it's 30 points in 3d space that are passed to the algorithm, and the confusing part is how the set of points were created.

Comment: That's what my doubt is, what is the use of the third value `z` when all I have to do is apply k-means to 2D points. However, thanks for `whitening is normalizing variance`. I get that part now. Maybe `z`, the third coordinate is used to divide the point set into well defined clusters so that we see some meaningful clusters when plotted.

Comment: @kamalbanga, I think the point of the example you linked to is to apply kmeans to 3d points.